# In XML, can you start a CDATA tag with &lt;?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, cdata

My javascript application interfaces with another and obtains some XML which contains CDATA.
Normally when dealing with CDATA I am aware it should look something similar to this:

However I am currently receiving this inside the XML:

```
<text>&lt;![CDATA[ Hello .... Thanks. ]]&gt;</text>
```

currently this does not work and it cannot tell if it is CDATA or not.

basically my question is can you start and end CDATA tags with &lt; and &gt; instead of < and >

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not CDATA. It is text.

`&lt;` means "A less that character". `<` means "Start of a tag/directive/etc"